# Is it possible to modify VCL styles at runtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I have a `TabControl` in which each tab represents a distinct set of data. My application uses `VCL Styles`, and thus setting `OwnerDraw` to `True` does not lead to `OnDrawTab` being called. I was wondering if it is possible to somehow intercept the routine which draws a specific control using `VCL Styles` (in my case, `TabControl`), and change the way the control is drawn (for instance, change the `Canvas.Font`, etc.).

Comment: See RRUZ answer to the question [close button of a tabsheet not supporting vcl styles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10535145/576719). You must introduce a style hook to the tab drawing.

Comment: @LURD I created a descendant of `TTabControlStyleHook` with the following code in the `DrawTab()` procedure. But it doesn't change the font at run time. Am I missing something? `procedure TTabControlStyleHookBtnClose.DrawTab(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer);
begin
  FontColor := Random(MaxInt);
  inherited;
end;
`

Comment: If you follow this link, [creating-colorful-tabsheets-with-the-vcl-styles](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/creating-colorful-tabsheets-with-the-vcl-styles/), RRUZ has a complete example of drawing the tabs with different text colours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the font color of a tabsheet using the vcl styles, you must override the DrawTab method of the Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabControlStyleHook style hook and use your own code to draw the tab and set the color font.

Try this sample

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet3: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet4: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet5: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet6: TTabSheet;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Themes;

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TTabFontColorStyleHook= class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabControlStyleHook)
  protected
    procedure DrawTab(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer); override;
  end;

  TWinControlClass = class(TWinControl);
  TCustomTabControlClass = class(TCustomTabControl);


procedure TTabFontColorStyleHook.DrawTab(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer);
var
  LDetails    : TThemedElementDetails;
  LImageIndex : Integer;
  LThemedTab  : TThemedTab;
  LIconRect   : TRect;
  R, LayoutR  : TRect;
  LImageW, LImageH, DxImage : Integer;
  LTextX, LTextY: Integer;
  LTextColor    : TColor;

    procedure DrawControlText(const S: string; var R: TRect; Flags: Cardinal);
    var
      TextFormat: TTextFormatFlags;
    begin
      Canvas.Font       := TWinControlClass(Control).Font;
      TextFormat        := TTextFormatFlags(Flags);
      Canvas.Font.Color := LTextColor;
      StyleServices.DrawText(Canvas.Handle, LDetails, S, R, TextFormat, Canvas.Font.Color);
    end;

    procedure AngleTextOut2(Canvas: TCanvas; Angle, X,
      Y: Integer; const Text: string);
    var
      LSavedDC: Integer;
    begin
      LSavedDC := SaveDC(Canvas.Handle);
      try
        SetBkMode(Canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT);
        Canvas.Font.Orientation := Angle;
        Canvas.TextOut(X, Y, Text);
      finally
        RestoreDC(Canvas.Handle, LSavedDC);
      end;
    end;

begin
  if (Images <> nil) and (Index < Images.Count) then
  begin
    LImageW := Images.Width;
    LImageH := Images.Height;
    DxImage := 3;
  end
  else
  begin
    LImageW := 0;
    LImageH := 0;
    DxImage := 0;
  end;

  R := TabRect[Index];
  if R.Left < 0 then Exit;

  if TabPosition in [tpTop, tpBottom] then
  begin
    if Index = TabIndex then
      InflateRect(R, 0, 2);
  end
  else if Index = TabIndex then
    Dec(R.Left, 2) else Dec(R.Right, 2);

  Canvas.Font.Assign(TCustomTabControlClass(Control).Font);
  LayoutR := R;
  LThemedTab := ttTabDontCare;
  //Get the type of the active tab
  case TabPosition of
    tpTop:
      begin
        if Index = TabIndex then
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemSelected
        else if (Index = HotTabIndex) and MouseInControl then
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemHot
        else
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemNormal;
      end;
    tpLeft:
      begin
        if Index = TabIndex then
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemLeftEdgeSelected
        else if (Index = HotTabIndex) and MouseInControl then
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemLeftEdgeHot
        else
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemLeftEdgeNormal;
      end;
    tpBottom:
      begin
        if Index = TabIndex then
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemBothEdgeSelected
        else if (Index = HotTabIndex) and MouseInControl then
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemBothEdgeHot
        else
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemBothEdgeNormal;
      end;
    tpRight:
      begin
        if Index = TabIndex then
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemRightEdgeSelected
        else if (Index = HotTabIndex) and MouseInControl then
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemRightEdgeHot
        else
          LThemedTab := ttTabItemRightEdgeNormal;
      end;
  end;

  //draw the tab
  if StyleServices.Available then
  begin
    LDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(LThemedTab);//necesary for  DrawControlText
    StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, LDetails, R);
  end;

  //get the index of the image (icon)
  if Control is TCustomTabControl then
    LImageIndex := TCustomTabControlClass(Control).GetImageIndex(Index)
  else
    LImageIndex := Index;

  //draw the image
  if (Images <> nil) and (LImageIndex >= 0) and (LImageIndex < Images.Count) then
  begin
    LIconRect := LayoutR;
    case TabPosition of
      tpTop, tpBottom:
        begin
          LIconRect.Left := LIconRect.Left + DxImage;
          LIconRect.Right := LIconRect.Left + LImageW;
          LayoutR.Left := LIconRect.Right;
          LIconRect.Top := LIconRect.Top + (LIconRect.Bottom - LIconRect.Top) div 2 - LImageH div 2;
          if (TabPosition = tpTop) and (Index = TabIndex) then
            OffsetRect(LIconRect, 0, -1)
          else
          if (TabPosition = tpBottom) and (Index = TabIndex) then
            OffsetRect(LIconRect, 0, 1);
        end;
      tpLeft:
        begin
          LIconRect.Bottom := LIconRect.Bottom - DxImage;
          LIconRect.Top := LIconRect.Bottom - LImageH;
          LayoutR.Bottom := LIconRect.Top;
          LIconRect.Left := LIconRect.Left + (LIconRect.Right - LIconRect.Left) div 2 - LImageW div 2;
        end;
      tpRight:
        begin
          LIconRect.Top := LIconRect.Top + DxImage;
          LIconRect.Bottom := LIconRect.Top + LImageH;
          LayoutR.Top := LIconRect.Bottom;
          LIconRect.Left := LIconRect.Left + (LIconRect.Right - LIconRect.Left) div 2 - LImageW div 2;
        end;
    end;
    if StyleServices.Available then
      StyleServices.DrawIcon(Canvas.Handle, LDetails, LIconRect, Images.Handle, LImageIndex);
  end;

  //draw the text of the tab
  if StyleServices.Available then
  begin

    //here you set the color of the font
    LTextColor:=clRed;

    if (TabPosition = tpTop) and (Index = TabIndex) then
      OffsetRect(LayoutR, 0, -1)
    else
    if (TabPosition = tpBottom) and (Index = TabIndex) then
      OffsetRect(LayoutR, 0, 1);

    if TabPosition = tpLeft then
    begin
      LTextX := LayoutR.Left + (LayoutR.Right - LayoutR.Left) div 2 - Canvas.TextHeight(Tabs[Index]) div 2;
      LTextY := LayoutR.Top + (LayoutR.Bottom - LayoutR.Top) div 2 + Canvas.TextWidth(Tabs[Index]) div 2;
      Canvas.Font.Color := LTextColor;
      AngleTextOut2(Canvas, 900, LTextX, LTextY, Tabs[Index]);
    end
    else
    if TabPosition = tpRight then
    begin
      LTextX := LayoutR.Left + (LayoutR.Right - LayoutR.Left) div 2 + Canvas.TextHeight(Tabs[Index]) div 2;
      LTextY := LayoutR.Top + (LayoutR.Bottom - LayoutR.Top) div 2 - Canvas.TextWidth(Tabs[Index]) div 2;
      Canvas.Font.Color := LTextColor;
      AngleTextOut2(Canvas, -900, LTextX, LTextY, Tabs[Index]);
    end
    else
     DrawControlText(Tabs[Index], LayoutR, DT_VCENTER or DT_CENTER or DT_SINGLELINE  or DT_NOCLIP);
  end;
end;



initialization
  TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TCustomTabControl, TTabFontColorStyleHook);
  TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TTabControl, TTabFontColorStyleHook);
end.
```

And this is the result

[image]

Also exist several resources which can help you when you need customize a tabsheet and pagecontrol components using vcl styles.

- [`Creating colorful tabsheets with the VCL Styles`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/creating-colorful-tabsheets-with-the-vcl-styles/)
- [Added border to TTabColorControlStyleHook](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/added-border-to-ttabcolorcontrolstylehook/)
- Check the code of the [Vcl.Styles.ColorTabs](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/browse/trunk/Common/Vcl.Styles.ColorTabs.pas) unit, which is part of the [vcl styles utils](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/browse/trunk/Common/Vcl.Styles.ColorTabs.pas) project.
- [How can i change text color of themed TabSheet caption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866751/how-can-i-change-text-color-of-themed-tabsheet-caption)

Comment: What if I just want to change the background color of the TTabbedNotebook. Must I enter a wall of code just to change a color?

Comment: Yes. This is the only way available to customize a `TCustomTabControl` descendant with the VCL Styles active.