# Changing the VCL Style at runtime leads to memory leak

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759379/is-it-possible-to-modify-vcl-styles-at-runtime), I tried to let the end user change my application's style at runtime. This has lead to a *very* long list of memory leaks with content like this:

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 12

This block was allocated by thread 0x130C, and the stack trace (return addresses) at
the time was: 404B3E [frxDsgnIntf.pas][System][@GetMem$qqri][1993] 454B77
[System.SysUtils][Sysutils.WideStrAlloc$qqrui] 454BB2 [System.SysUtils]
Sysutils.StrNew$qqrpxb] 53046E [Vcl.Controls][Controls.TWinControl.DestroyWnd$qqrv]
57E1C7 [Vcl.ComCtrls][Comctrls.TCustomTreeView.DestroyWnd$qqrv] A53DEE [JvComCtrls]
TJvTreeView.DestroyWnd$qqrv] 530733 [Vcl.Controls]
Controls.TWinControl.DestroyHandle$qqrv] 530703 [Vcl.Controls]
Controls.TWinControl.DestroyHandle$qqrv] 530703 [Vcl.Controls]
Controls.TWinControl.DestroyHandle$qqrv] 7552FEB6 [EnumThreadWindows] 530703
[Vcl.Controls][Controls.TWinControl.DestroyHandle$qqrv]

The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown
```

Almost all of the leaks are in `frxDsgnIntf.pas`, except for all the components on the form which lets the user to change the style and all point to this procedure:

```
with TdlgSettings.Create(nil) do // leak here according to FastMM report
  try
    if ShowModal = mrOk then;
  finally
    Release;
  end;
```

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or this is the *expected* behavior of `TStyleManager` when changing styles? Here's the code which changes the style at runtime:

```
procedure TdlgSettings.cbThemeChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(cbTheme.Text); // cbTheme.Items lists all the themes which are included the application
end;
```

Comment: `frx` indicates it's FastReports, which has nothing to do with styles, and `DsgnIntf` means it's only code which is used at designtime in the IDE. IOW, you have a non-issue here.

Comment: @KenWhite Two points: 1) Why is FastMM complaining about memory leaks if frxDsgnIntf.pas is not linked into my application? 2) At the end of the leak report, there is indication of a memory leak inside my application which only happens when I call `TStyleManager.TrySetStyle(cbTheme.Text);`. It seems like when `TStyleManager` changes the current set style, active form is not properly released/recreated.

Answer (score 0):

```
uses
Vcl.Styles, Vcl.Themes,
uFixMemOverflowVclStyle;
```

LINK: http://www.delphi4arab.net/forum/showthread.php?t=9607

Comment: broken link. site not in English anyway.